# How to Set Scatter Plot Hover Info With Pandas Dataframe Column in Python With Plotly

Tags: python, pandas, hover, plotly, scatter-plot

I am using pandas to generate the data for my plotly scatter plot. However when I try to convert a column to a list for the hoverinfo I am unable to successfully compile.

I am using the list function. I have also tried data['id'].values, and data['id'].tolist.

```
hoverList = list(data.id)
display = go.Scatter(
    x = data['x_data'],
    y = data['y_data'],
    hoverinfo = 'hoverList',
    mode = 'markers',
    name = "data",
    marker = dict(
    size = 6,
    color = 'rgba(76, 224, 128, 0.79)'
    )
)
```

Output recieved:

> Invalid value of type 'builtins.str' received for the 'hoverinfo' property of scatter
>           Received value: 'hoverList'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved the problem. It looks like the hoverinfo paramater can only be 'x', 'y', 'z', 'text', or a few other specified commands. Here is the code that compiled:

```
display = go.Scatter(
    x = data['x_data'],
    y = data['y_data'],
    text = data['id'],
    hoverinfo = 'text',
    mode = 'markers',
    name = "data",
    marker = dict(
    size = 6,
    color = 'rgba(76, 224, 128, 0.79)'
    )
)
```